Mailu limit number of emails send in a month/Day
Is it possible to limit the users to send total email in a month/day by using mailu.
Example 1. user1@example.com: can send only 100 emails a day & 3000 emails in a month. 2. user2@example.com: can send only 200 emails a day & 6000 emails in a month.

Yes, it might be possible, but it has to be done on the server side. The question is a bit unclear. If it's referring to the local server, then yes, it's possible. If it's referring to a random server, it will be more complicated or (nearly) impossible
